# Two-Way Binding is not working in Blazor Component

Tags: asp.net, validation, blazor, razor-pages

I am working on a ASP.NET Blazor App in .NET 8. A model class `SubjectName` is bound with this `SubjectForm.razor` blazor component.

```
@inject ISubjectNameRepo Repo

@if(Subject is not null)
{
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <EditForm Enhance="true" method="post" FormName="SubjectForm" Model="Subject" OnValidSubmit="AddOrEditSubject" OnInvalidSubmit="InvSubmit" autocomplete="off">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
                <h3>@Title</h3>
                @if (IsEditMode)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" name="Subject.Id" value="@Subject.Id"/>
                }
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="subname" class="form-label">
                        Subject Name
                    </label>
                    <InputText id="subname" @bind-Value="Subject.SubName" class="form-control shadow-none" />
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-none">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                    <a href="/subjects/list" class="btn btn-secondary shadow-none ms-3">
                        Back to List
                    </a>
                </div>
                <ValidationSummary />
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div>
        The subject is null ghere
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsEditMode { get; set; } = false;

    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public SubjectName? Subject { get; set; }

    public string Title => IsEditMode ? $"Edit Subject {Id}" : "Add New Subject";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<SubjectName> OnValidSubjectNameSubmit { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (IsEditMode)
        {
            Subject ??= await Repo.GetByIdAsync(Id);
        }
        else
        {
            Subject ??= new();
        }
    }

    private async Task AddOrEditSubject()
    {
        await OnValidSubjectNameSubmit.InvokeAsync(Subject);
    }

    private async Task InvSubmit()
    {
        
    }

}
```

Below is the code of `SubjectName` model class

```
    public class SubjectName
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id {  get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Subject Name")]
        public string? SubName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EvaluationTweak>? EvaluationTweaks { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run this app, navigate to this page, enter the data and then click "Submit" button, then the contents of the `InputText` vanish and it display a messahe `Subject Name field is required`

I am unable to understand whats wronf there?

Comment: When it get to the `AddOrEditSubject`, are the data in `Subject` variable there or already not? 
What do you do on ` OnValidSubjectNameSubmit` invocation?

Comment: No, it does not have data at that moment. I know this because when is remove validations and data annotations, then it saves empty strings to the database. The 'OnValidSubjactNameSubmit' is not being invoked because it is conditioned to invoke only if data is validted.

Comment: So it doesn't get into the OnValidSubmit method, right? I think you have to specify the form in attibute: `  [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName ="SubjectForm" )]`

Comment: I just tried this after reading your reply but it didn't work.

Comment: If you prepare and publish runnable code with the problem I will look into that. I think it is something simple, that just cannot see right now.

Comment: I have prepared a publish (folder). How to share it with you now?

Comment: please check difripedia.com

Comment: I need the code to be able to help you. GitHub repo would be the best. I don't need the full repo, just the part where the issue is -  in a simplified way. Minimal reproducible example.

Comment: here is the repo pls https://github.com/FAhmedN/GetTutorsOnlineCopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird. I know the solution, but it is rather a fix. The true reason stays hidden for me.

The outer layer of the issue is that the `Subject` property is null when submitting the form. It should have the values from the form. The form is submitted correctly.

I will show only the relevant part:

Model you are binding to form:

```
public class SubjectName
{
  public string? SubName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<EvaluationTweak>? EvaluationTweaks { get; set; }
}
```

Problem here are the `EvaluationTweaks`, if you remove them, everything work as expected. Now the reason why. Check the `EvaluationTweak` class:

```
public class EvaluationTweak
{
    [Required]
    public virtual SubjectName Subject { get; set; } = new();
}
```

When you remove the `Subject` property, it will also work... Note that you can replace it with `int SubjectId` so you keep the reference there. Also note that removing  `Subject` property from `EvaluationTweak` will not change the db schema.

But why is that a problem? I have no idea, my guess is - it has somehow problem with serialization? It is perceived as circular reference maybe?

Would be nice to investigate further.

Comment: Great Job, its worked for me...... But let me share my experience today with you. It might give you an insight into the problem. I was previously using SQLite. Today I shifted to SQL Server. When I tried to update database using npm, it told me to remove some references or change their delete action from cascading to NoAction. It confirms your doubt to circular reference. I am realy thankful to you for this support. Thumbs up.........